# Optimise a Python/ C++ algorithm

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, optimization

I was participating in a competitive programming contest, and faced a question where out of four test cases, my answer was correct in 3, but exceeded time limit in 4th.

I tried to get better results by converting my code from python to cpp (**I know that time complexity remains same, but it was worth a shot :)**)

Following is the question:

> A string is said to be using strong language if it contains at least K consecutive characters '*'.
> You are given a string S with length N. Determine whether it uses strong language or not.

**Input**:

- The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
- The first line of each test case contains two space-separated integers N and K.
- The second line contains a single string S with length N.

**Output**:

> Print a single line containing the string "YES" if the string contains strong language or "NO" if it does not

My python approach:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    k = int(input().split()[1])
    s = input()
    s2 = "".join(["*"]*k)
    if len(s.split(s2))>1:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

My converted Cpp code (**converted it myself**)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        /* code */
        int n,k;
        std::cin >> n >> k;
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        string str2(k,'*');

        size_t found = str.find(str2);
        if (found != string::npos){
            std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please guide me how can I reduce my time complexity?

Other approaches : "Using find() function instead of split or using for loop"

Edit:
*Sample Input :*

```
2
5 1
abd
5 2
*i**j
```

Output :

```
NO
YES
```

Comment: Can you post a sample input file?

Comment: I don't know what `std::string::find` does under the hood, but if you are looking for a consectutive stretch of N asterisks, you could check whether every Nth character is an asterisk, which will catch all such stretches, but also shorter ones. If you have a hit, count how many asterisks are before and after that. That will save you time, but only if N is large.

Comment: @MOehm Actually if the shorter ones are there but the accurate stretch is not there, the answer will not be correct, please refer to the edited test case.

Comment: Did you get a TLE on your CPP submission?

Comment: @ProfessorofStupidity Yes on the same test case in both Python and Cpp. To add on 1≤K≤N≤10^6

Actually tile limit was different for both Python and Cpp, 5sec and 1 sec respectively

Comment: Yeah! I found the question. You've got to do better than O(n) in this question. Maybe read about other string matching algorithms from GFG maybe or cp-algorithms.com. It might help you...

Comment: Okay will refer to them @ProfessorofStupidity Thank You

Comment: Finding an asterisk at N*k is a necessary, but not a sufficient condition. You must always check the surrounding characters, and that's what I say in my comment. Having a lot of "false hits"  can degrade the performance, but the algorithm is correct, I think. In your  example, you will find `*`, `*` and `j`. Now count the asterisks to both sides of the `*`'s. The first one is a miss, but the second one isn't.

Comment: Why not just `if '*' * K in S: print('YES')`? Or `print('YES' if '*' * K in S else 'NO')` ? Does that give the TLE error? It's O(n) though.

Comment: @aneroid yes it does, actually linear time complexity is not sufficient we have to get it to a lesser time complexity, although it is indeed a cleaner solution

Comment: @MOehm I am unable to understand what you mean by false hits would you like to get in a chatroom? : [Link for chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230676/discussion-of-question)

Other are also invited

Comment: I don't chat. Say you have a long string with ten consecutive `*`. If you test every 10th character, you will "hit" one of these asterisks. But because you can't be sure that you have at least 10 of them, you must check the surrounding characters. If there are fewer than 10, you have a "false hit". Here, "hit" refers to whether the probed character is a `*`, true and false reer to whether there are actually 10 in a row.

Comment: You could also go and study the algorithms the Professor suggested and come across the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm), which works from a similar premise: It advances the places to look for based on possible matches. I think if your search string is uniform, you'll get something similar to what I suggested.

Comment: If this is an ongoing contest I won't be able to provide a solution. However, looking at the different articles from Python and the C++ docs, it looks like the worst-case search results could give slow results, although the average and best case performances are good. I suggest you implement an algorithm yourself that takes advantage of the specific structure of the substring you need to match - since it consists of repeated characters it should be straightforward.

Comment: I don't think in this case there is anything faster than direct scan through all the chars. Have you tried use plain loop?

Comment: or it create a pretty huge string that take long time for allocation and deallocation, you can bypass this by read char by char (the buffered input stream should be able to take care of the possible performance penalty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds you posted suggest that linear time is OK in Python. You can simply keep a running track of how many asterisks you have seen in a row.

```
T = int(input())
for _ in range(T):
    n, k = map(int, input())
    s = input()
    count, ans = 0, False
    for c in s:
        if c == "*":
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 0
        ans = ans or count >= k
    if ans:
        print("NO")
    else:
        print("YES")
```

I can also tell you why you are TLE'ing. Consider the case where `n = 1e6`, `k = 5e5`, and `s` is a string where the first `k-1` characters are asterisks. The find method you have is going to check every position for matching the `str2` you created. This will take O(n^2) time, giving you a TLE.

Comment: I modified your code a little bit and applied some suggestions by @MOehm and it worked out,

Thank You very much :)

Comment: @trincot Each call to "find" will be linear, as it has to check every consecutive position. find does not know or check a priori that all the characters are the same, thus find is called on every position until there is a match.

Comment: @JerryHalisberry, that is an assumption about how `find` works. Can you provide evidence?

Comment: @trincot This is the standard. You can check cppreference yourself: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: That reference does not specify the algorithm.

Comment: @trincot It clearly specifies the complexity, making the algorithm obvious.

Comment: OK, if it's obvious to you, I will leave it at that.

Comment: If you are wondering why it says the complexity is "unspecified" but later defines it anyways, you get large performance boosts when the string is such that there are fewer false positives.

Comment: actually @trincot my algorithm ( find / split ) was surely linear but in his algorithm ( or MOhem ) The time complexity is reduced since if the count is matched prior to the complete iterations then it will display the results, basically in hist time complexity is : O(n-t), while in find or split it is O(n+k)